what can be overaligned types
is "Tis overaligned" equivalent to alignof(T)>alignof(std::max_align_t)? And is it possible to have an overaligned type without using alignas keyword or another explicit alignment mechanism (in which case, could an example be provided)?

Yes, and yes (since many compilers have their own extension for alignment, which predates alignas being added to the language).

@Eljay edited the question wrt to your comment

"T is overaligned" is actually equivalent to alignof(T)>alignof(std::max_align_t): for instance in C++20 (emphasis mine):

An extended alignment is represented by an alignment greater than alignof(std​::​max_­align_­t). It is implementation-defined whether any extended alignments are supported and the contexts in which they are supported ([dcl.align]). A type having an extended alignment requirement is an over-aligned type.

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.align#3
This is an example of overaligned type without explicit alignment mechanism, using non standard type (from AVX):
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << alignof(std::max_align_t);
    std::cout << '\t';
    std::cout << alignof(__m256); // __m256 is an AVX type
}

LIVE
Output varies with the hardware and, sometimes, alignof(__m256) is strictly greater than alignof(std::max_align_t).
I couldn't think of a standard-only example.
